# Pulse animation on iPhone

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone

Using cocos2d, how can I achieve a pulse animation using actions.

I know I'll need `CCScaleTo` and probably `CCRepeat`, but I don't know how to put them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness in addition to James' spot on answer above, you need to call  the method *[runAction ...]* on your CCNode object and pass it the action - That is, the code provided by James as is.

To stop the pulsating effect, you can call [stopAllActions ...] on your CCNode.

Best,

Answer (score 2):

Got it almost straight away! This pulses an object forever with a period of 2 seconds and scales up 10%.

```
[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
    [CCSequence actions:
      [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1.0f scale:1.1f],
      [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1.0f scale:1.0f],
      nil]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Or CCFadeTo depending on how you want your animation to look...

```
- (void) pulseStop {
    [mySprite stopAllActions];
}

- (void) pulseStart {
    [mySprite setOpacity:1.0];
    CCFadeTo *fadeToIn = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:1.0 opacity:50];
    CCFadeTo *fadeToOut = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:1.0 opacity:255];

    [mySprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actionOne:fadeToIn two:fadeToOut]]];
}
```